# No data being sent to consumers, even though connection and session are created

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

The ActiveMQ Artemis servers in our system recently started exhibiting an issue where the consumers are establishing a connection to the server, but no data is being processed. Has anyone seen something like this?  If so, any suggestions on what could be the problem? **No changes have been made to the consumer software, and it was previously working.** Here is what we are seeing and what we have tried with troubleshooting.

**Configuration:**

- Two ActiveMQ servers in replication pair, not using a shared storage (config files below)
- OS is Red Hat 7.9
- ActiveMQ Artemis version is 2.21. We are looking at upgrading version. I work for the gov and they are typically behind on releases. (**correction:** version was originally listed as 2.12, which was a typo)

**Troubleshooting:**

Verified through netstat that a connection is established.

Also verified through the website console that sessions are being created by the Java consumers, and and only 1 instance of each. Our servers are processing and logging warnings for deduplication, so I know the data is correctly entering the multicast queues. The deduplication messages are normal. We have two input producers for redundancy and AMQ drops the dups on purpose.

SELinux is not logging any errors, and the firewall isn't blocking anything since the connections are being established.

Java version hasn't changed for Artemis server or consumers.

Java consumers (connecting on `61616`) are logging that they establish a connection, but no messages coming in.

We took a pcap and opened the capture in Wireshark and confirmed the data is coming from the broker to the consumer. We did notice that the capture showed `.` between every character in the XML string we are sending through Artemis, and were not sure if this was standard for the Artemis protocol.

Master `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <name>0.0.0.0</name>
    <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
    <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
    <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
    <id-cache-size>5</id-cache-size>
    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
    <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
    <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
    <journal-buffer-timeout>20000</journal-buffer-timeout>
    <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
    <connectors>
      <connector name="artemis">tcp://192.168.20.30:61616</connector>
    </connectors>
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
    <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
    <page-sync-timeout>180000</page-sync-timeout>
    <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
    </acceptors>
    <broadcast-groups>
      <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <group-address>1.2.3.4</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
      </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>
    <discovery-groups>
      <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <group-address>1.2.3.4</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
      </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>
    <cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>0</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
      </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
    <cluster-user>me</cluster-user>
    <cluster-password>password</cluster-password>
    <ha-policy>
      <replication>
        <master>
          <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
          <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
        </master>
      </replication>
    </ha-policy>
    <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
      </security-setting>
    </security-settings>
    <address-settings>
      <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address/>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
      </address-setting>
      <address-setting match="MyQueues">
        <!-- note: not the default "#" -->
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <expiry-delay>10000</expiry-delay>
        <expiry-address/>
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
        <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
        <auto-delete-addresses-delay>10000</auto-delete-addresses-delay>
      </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
    <address-queue-scan-period>-1</address-queue-scan-period>
    <addresses>
      <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="DLQ"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
      <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="ExpiryQueue"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
    </addresses>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

Slave:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <name>0.0.0.0</name>
    <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
    <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
    <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
    <id-cache-size>5</id-cache-size>
    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
    <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
    <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
    <journal-buffer-timeout>24000</journal-buffer-timeout>
    <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
    <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
    <page-sync-timeout>184000</page-sync-timeout>
    <global-max-messages>-1</global-max-messages>
    <connectors>
      <connector name="artemis">tcp://192.168.20.31:61616</connector>
    </connectors>
    <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
    </acceptors>
    <broadcast-groups>
      <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <group-address>1.2.3.4</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
      </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>
    <discovery-groups>
      <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <group-address>1.2.3.4</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
      </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>
    <cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>0</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
      </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
    <ha-policy>
      <replication>
        <slave>
          <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
        </slave>
      </replication>
    </ha-policy>
    <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
      </security-setting>
    </security-settings>
    <address-settings>
      <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address/>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
      </address-setting>
      <address-setting match="MyQueues">
        <!--not the default "#" -->
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <expiry-delay>10000</expiry-delay>
        <expiry-address/>
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
        <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
        <auto-delete-addresses-delay>10000</auto-delete-addresses-delay>
      </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
    <address-queue-scan-period>-1</address-queue-scan-period>
    <addresses>
      <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="DLQ"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
      <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="ExpiryQueue"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
    </addresses>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

We left the system up and running overnight, and it just started working. Didn't touch anything over night. Any thoughts? We are stupefied.

Comment: The deduplication messages are normal.  We have two input producers for redundancy and AMQ drops the dups on purpose.  I will check message counts today and get back to you.  We are looking at upgrading version.  I work for the gov and they are typically behind on releases.  We see the messages by using a packet sniffer on the server where the consumers are, but the consumers aren't logging they are receiving the message but the packet sniffer says otherwise.

Comment: We did do a security patch on Friday, so I'm also going to check some things about the patch.  Typically SELinux would log denials after a security patch but it is not logging anything so I don't think it's that.  We do have a working test system, so there is a nuclear option, but it would be nice to know the cause and what specifically could interfere with the producers or consumers.

Comment: We left the system up and running overnight and it just started working.  Didnt touch anything over night.  Any thoughts? We are stuplified.

Comment: yea, i went in to check for the requested message counts etc, and when we brought up our software it worked.  

What is the best way to look for a blocked consumer? just checking the message counts?

Comment: "When we brought up our software it worked" - Sorry, I just meant "we just ran and tested our system, which includes having our consumers connect to AMQ".  Short answer, is that our consumers just randomly started processing the data over night. 

During troubleshooting before, we restarted our consumer programs.   Wouldn't that terminate a blocked consumer connection?  I feel like if it was a blocked consumer, restarting the consumer program would have closed the consumer connection.

Comment: I compiled the information from my comments into an answer of sorts. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For additional trouble-shooting you should gather these details in the web console in the "Attributes" tab for the relevant queue:

- Message Count
- Delivering Count
- Consumer Count

If the consumer count is 0 then you know that the broker doesn't believe there is a consumer connected and that is why it is not receiving any messages.

If the consumer count is 1 and the message count is 0 and the delivering count is 0 then there are no messages in the queue to consume which is why the consumer is not receiving any messages.

If the consumer count is 1 and the delivering count is > 0 then the broker has delivered those messages to the consumer and the consumer should be consuming them. If the consumer is *not* consuming them that indicates the consumer is blocked/stuck for some reason. In this case you should get [thread dumps](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) from the consumer and look for threads which are explicitly in a `BLOCKED` state or stuck in a blocking call of some kind.

A few things to keep in mind:

- Many times consumers get blocked working with resources *other* than the broker (e.g. remote file-system, REST API, database, etc.). In this situation restarting the consuming application will recreate the connection, etc. to the message broker, but it may not resolve whatever condition was blocking the consumer in the first place.
- When a consumer is blocked the broker will still send messages to it (which will be stored in the consumer's internal message buffer - at least until the buffer fills up) but since it is blocked it won't actually consume them.
- You can't know for sure that a consumer is really stuck by looking at statistics on the broker. You have to have thread dumps from the consumer to know that for sure. [Slow consumer detection](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/slow-consumers.html) may help here.

In any event, you can't know what's happening for sure without more information. I'm just guessing at this point, but given the information you've provided a blocked/stuck consumer seems a good guess.

Lastly, the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) is 2.27.1. You should consider upgrading, although I'm not suggesting this will necessarily solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Justin, you have been a huge help, as always.  Appreciate it! Since the consumers started processing again, we are going to implement some utilities to look for blocked consumers if this happens again.  Going to mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this or encountered the issue again? we are facing the same and so am looking for ways to debug this further.

Comment: @sg1973, did you already gather all the diagnostic data detailed in my answer? If so, what was the result of the investigation?

Comment: Hi Justin, Not yet. The issue is very sporadic and is not easily reproducible which is why i was thinking if there is any setting to prevent this from happening. Will keep you posted

Comment: There's no way to know if it is preventable until you know exactly why it's happening as there are many possible reasons (e.g. stuck or buggy client, bug on the broker, network trouble, etc.). You need to provide more details to make a determination. If you get more details and wish to pursue this further you need to open a new question.