# ActiveMQ Artemis - prevent permanent stalling of messages

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have an ActiveMQ Artemis instance with a queue that is populated on a sporadic basis and does not empty.

Viewing the queue through the web console shows 63 messages in the queue, none of which display on the "Browse Queue" page. The messages cannot be purged. Performing a purge results in no changes.

The "Delivering Count" is also at 63, but none of the consumers are actively running processes that would be caused by these messages and the queue size has remained unchanged for many times longer than would be needed to process a message from this queue.

What I think is happening is that these messages were delivered, and the consumer stopped during a deployment and so never acknowledged.

What I don't understand is why this status would persist indefinitely, or how I can either get rid or re-queue for processing these invisible and un-moving messages.

I've tried purging the queue to no effect.
I've tried restarting all the consumers to no effect.

Comment: After closing all the consumers the delivering messages should come back into the queue. Can you add the simple steps to reproduce this issue to the question?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino well, not really. As I've no solid idea what causes it. The infrequent fill of this queue triggered again this morning with no outages/disruption and the invisible queue has increased again. So it clearly isn't as simple as "lost when power goes off" that I originally though.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Typically this kind of thing is caused by a stalled consumer (e.g. as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792977/no-data-being-sent-to-consumers-even-though-connection-and-session-are-created)). However, if you close _all_ the consumers and the Delivering Count is still > 0 that would indicate a problem with the broker. To be clear, messages "in delivery" cannot be purged or browsed directly so what you're seeing there is expected.

Comment: @JustinBertram Artemis 2.17.0

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend you move to the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) which is 2.33.0 at this point. Version 2.17.0 was released in early 2021 over 3 years ago now. There's been 21 other releases since then with hundreds of bugs fixed. I can't say conclusively that you're hitting a bug, but if you are then it may already be fixed.